# Only wrap certain text around an image?

Tags: html, css

I used `float:right` on an image to wrap text to the left of it, however there is still some space left below the text and any more text I write goes there, to the left of the image. How can I make it so that new text is added below the image, not next to it?

All I've tried so far is to add `<br>` over and over again so the text goes where it should, but that is obviously not a good solution. I did think of just using a table instead of floating the image to the right, but I still don't think that's a good solution.

Here's my code:

```css
font {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: black;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-icon.png" style="max-width: 15%;float:right;margin-right: 200px">
<div style="margin-left:200px">
  <h1>
    <font>
      Some text
    </font>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You need `overflow-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-spaces;` css on text div and also put some width over it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `flex` for your problem:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.imageWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>

    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
      <div>
        More Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>
      <font>
        Some text
      </font>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```